# How to deploy flutter web app directly from my flutter project repo

Tags: flutter, web-applications, github-pages

I have created a flutter app and hosted my whole flutter files on this repo. I am now looking for a way to host the web app for it generated by flutter. Most tutorials I asks me to create a {myusername}.github.io repo and host it using github pages there.

However, I would like to host it directly from my existing repo. Is it possible? like, can i choose the hosting folder as /root/build/web instead of just /root?

I want the url to be myusername.github.io/myreponame

Forgive me for any ilogical questions since I'm a beginner to flutter and github in general. Thank you :)

I tried getting to the github pages in settings and place index.html in root of repo. However this did not help.